# Android Call logs return zero results

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver, calllog

I am trying to get the call records for multi sim for a given period of time last ten minutes for the iccid. When I check the cursor count it always return zero records. Is there something wrong with the query? I double checked the time window and the iccid arguments to make sure they are not empty or null.

```
 cursor = context.getContentResolver()
              .query(
                  Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                  new String[] {Calls.TYPE, Calls.NUMBER, Calls.DATE},
                  Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID + "  LIKE ? AND " + Calls.DATE + " > ? ",
                  new String[] {iccId + "%", ten_mins_ago},
                  Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

Comment: there's something wrong with your post. In line `Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID + "  LIKE ? AND " + Calls.DATE + " > ?”` the last quotation is not a "normal" one. Is it your code or SO messed here?

Comment: updated . it was SO that messed up the formatting